# Doing context-aware previews in the WordPress Customizer

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

Initially I was using `active_callback` to make my Customizer controls contextual in nature, and was satisfied with the kind product I had with it. But then I cam across [this article](https://richtabor.com/wordpress-customizer-context-aware-previews/) about Content-aware previews in Customizer. It is awesome.

In that article, the author has used his own plugin to get the page value. I got everything from the JavaScript enqueued for the controls and the previews, what I didn't get is; what could be the page value for a post or a page or a custom post type here.

```
$page = Login_Designer()->get_login_designer_page();
```

Is anyone doing something similar with Customizer? Please share how this can be doable with the different page types.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code is using `get_permalink( $page )`, I would guess that $page holds an ID.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

In my opinion, it's not always a good thing to switch the preview to another page for the user.